# call a helper function and create a progress bar on django

Tags: django, html, progress-bar, meter

I want to make a progress bar for a poll. I use django 1.4.8 for the implementation. The progress bar should display a rercentage of people who have already vote. There is also a helper function which return the sum of users voted.

At first i edit the template and the css to display the bar. After that, i try to use jquery for the actual behavor. But I am lost. I searched on the internet but i could make understanding in a clear manner. I am not sure which is the right way to do it. I dont want to use any other external library.

So, the question is how to call the help function and where i ll use the value to display the proper percentage on the progress bar into the template?

Comment: Do you want to update progress bar "on the fly", without page refresh?

Comment: You have either to call the server periodically (via a Ajax call) and see what's going on, or you have to use some kind of realtime thingy on your server to push data to your browser. The former is easy to do and can work pretty well, the later is more complex and you'll have to tweaks things in the server. Google "realtime django".

Answer (score 1):

You need to think about how the web browser and the server (Django) communicate.

The browser makes a 'get' request to a url on the server. In Django you have an *urls.py* file which determines which *view* will handle requests to that url. For example there will be a view which renders a template containing the HTML code for the poll form.

When the user submits the poll, the browser makes a 'post' request, sending the form data for the poll to the server - to a specific Django view which handles saving the poll vote to the database. Usually in Django we'd use the same view function for both the get and the post for a form - see this answer for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21114637/202168

It's not clear whether you want to show the progress bar initially, or only after they've submitted their vote. Either way you just need to calculate the relevant values for percentage and sum of users in your Django view and pass those values into the template, which renders the HTML sent back to the browser.

If you're using an [HTML5 progress bar](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/html5-progress-bar/) you don't even need jQuery. Unless you want a user to see the progress bar changing as *other* users submit their votes (much more complicated) you don't need any 'ajax' stuff either.

I suggest first you start with the Django tutorial:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/

Comment: i was a little bit confused but your advice and the links help me a lot. I knew i had to edit the view but i was not sure how exactly. In fact the bar will appear when a user vote in another page with the results. What you make clear is the usage of jquery why, when and how. btw I have already started reading the docs.Thank u a lot.

Answer (score 0):

So to be accurate the helper.py imports register from jingo. This means you call the function instantly into template. Furthermore I used  instead of  for my purpose.

helper.py

```
from jingo import register

@register.filter
def get_value():
     return value
```

into template

```
<meter min="0" value="{{ <app_name>|get_value }} max="1"></meter>
```